# pymongo sort() limit() different?

Tags: sorting, find, limit, pymongo

```
1. db.bios.find().sort( { name: 1 } ).limit( 5 )
2. db.bios.find().limit( 5 ).sort( { name: 1 } )
```

1. What is the different with them? They are equal?
2. If first one doing: find all documents? it is bad.
   If db.bios.find().count() is very big(1000000), which process fast?
3. what is find() default sequence? the insert sequence?
   Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.These two are equal, sorting will be done first, and then the result will be limited. 
2.In order to optimize this, consider having index on *name*, if this is going to be a frequent query. 
3. The natural order for find() is, in general, insertion order, though it is not guaranteed if the documents were updated after creation.